# ¿Cómo controlar los días no habiles en sql-server?

Tags: sql-server, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo que validar si al ingresar una fecha, ésta es sábado, domingo o feriado, si así que genere un mensaje tengo el siguiente cod.

TENGO LA siguiente query:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendario(
    Fecha   date CONSTRAINT PK_Calendario PRIMARY KEY,
    EsFeriado   bit,
    EsFinDeSemana   bit,
    --Cualquier cantidad de columnas que requieras para cálculos de fechas
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DiasHabiles ON Calendario(Fecha) WHERE EsFeriado = 0 AND EsFinDeSemana = 0;

WITH 
    E(n) AS(
        SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
    ),
    E2(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
    ),
    E4(n) AS(
        SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
    ),
    cteCalendario(Fecha) AS(
        SELECT  DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2000') Fecha
        FROM E4
    )
INSERT INTO Calendario
SELECT Fecha,
       CASE WHEN Fecha IN('20190916', '20190501', '20191225', '20190101'/*, etc*/) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       --CASE WHEN Fecha IN(SELECT Fecha FROM Feriados) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( DD, '19000101', Fecha) % 7 IN (5,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM cteCalendario c;
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: que no lo entiendo bien por ejemplo para indicarle cuales son sabados y domingos

Comment: Para saber si es es fin de semana usa `datepart` en lugar de `datediff` `datepart(dw, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

(Variables para la fecha a validar)
DECLARE @FechaIngresada DATE = '2023-01-01';

```
(Consulta para validar si la fecha es feriado, fin de semana o día hábil)
SELECT
    Fecha,
    EsFeriado,
    EsFinDeSemana,
    CASE
        WHEN EsFeriado = 1 THEN 'Es feriado'
        WHEN EsFinDeSemana = 1 THEN 'Es fin de semana'
        ELSE 'Es día hábil'
    END AS Estado
FROM
    Calendario
WHERE
    Fecha = @FechaIngresada;
```

Esta consulta verifica si la fecha ingresada se encuentra en la tabla Calendario y devuelve información sobre si es feriado, fin de semana o día hábil.

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: En base al script que proporcionó OP, ¿cómo responde tu script a la pregunta?

Comment: muchas gracias, por a probar (Y)

Comment: @padaleiana en el apartado (consulta para validad si la fecha es feriado, fin de semana o dia habil) Eso es lo que desea